# AVFoundation Video recording volume control

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am working over an app that has video recording and user can adjust volume in it. I have done it using AVFoundation. I have initialised `AVCaptureSession` and added a `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` as audio and video output in it. I am also attaching a piece of code over here.

```
    AVCaptureSession *session = _captureSession;
    if (![session.sessionPreset isEqualToString:_captureSessionPreset]) {
    if ([session canSetSessionPreset:_captureSessionPreset]) {
        session.sessionPreset = _captureSessionPreset;
    } else {
        newError = [VideoRecorder createError:@"Cannot set session preset"];
    }
}
_videoOutputAdded = NO;
if (self.videoConfiguration.enabled) {
    if (_videoOutput == nil) {
        _videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
        _videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = NO;
        [_videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_sessionQueue];
    }

    if (![session.outputs containsObject:_videoOutput]) {
        if ([session canAddOutput:_videoOutput]) {
            [session addOutput:_videoOutput];
            _videoOutputAdded = YES;
        } else {
            if (newError == nil) {
                newError = [VideoRecorder createError:@"Cannot add videoOutput inside the session"];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        _videoOutputAdded = YES;
    }
}

_audioOutputAdded = NO;
if (self.audioConfiguration.enabled) {
    if (_audioOutput == nil) {
        _audioOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
        [_audioOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_sessionQueue];
    }

    if (![session.outputs containsObject:_audioOutput]) {
        if ([session canAddOutput:_audioOutput]) {
            [session addOutput:_audioOutput];
            _audioOutputAdded = YES;
        } else {
            if (newError == nil) {
                newError = [VideoRecorder createError:@"Cannot add audioOutput inside the sesssion"];
            }
        }
    } else {
        _audioOutputAdded = YES;
    }
}
```

How can I adjust volume of `AVCaptureConnection` that is associated with this `AVCaptureSession` because it seems it is only available for mac?

How can I adjust recording volume while recording?

Please let me know if there is any other way to implement this.